# How to Get Current User in Backend with Firebase in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I am so confused,
all the Firebase authentication tutorial online are teaching how to login in frontend,

of course you can get the token and send it to server for verification if its a post request,

but what about normal get request like a page request? I have installed firebase-admin already but i didnt find any method for getting current user........

i am using node and express

for example

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    const idToken = (where can i get the token??)
    console.log(idToken);
    res.render('index.ejs');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You still have to arrange for the auth token to be sent in the HTTP request.  You can do that with a header in the request.  [Sample code showing exactly this case](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint) can be found in the [official samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/).  This will work for any HTTP method, and is a lot better than trying to use a POST body.

The sample uses the `Authorization` header to transmit the token and `verifyIdToken()` to make sure it's valid.

Comment: thanks, so there isnt a way to make a simple isAuthenticated middle ware in backend?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the code sample does that I linked to.